# AIR Window Scale and Stage Scale

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have an AIR application that I would like to allow the user to scale from 60% to 200%. I have added a slider in an options menu that controls the scaling of the application.  I'm confused on how to go about scaling the entire application properly and need a little help, I've been at this for quite some time now.

The code for this simple test is below. In adding traces everywhere and putting listeners on resize events, I have basically discovered that setting the scaleX and scaleY value of the window does not change the scaleX and scaleY of the stage.  But, these stage values cannot be edited and an error is thrown if you try.

So, then I tried adjusting the stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight to match stage.width and stage.height. But, in doing that, the contents of the window are scaled again.

Basically what ends up happening is with anything over 100%, or the minWidth & minHeight, components inside the window end up clipping with parts appearing cut off because the stage.stageWidth is not as wide as the stage.width and stage.stageHeight is not as tall as the stage.height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Window xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="250" height="300"
          minWidth="260" minHeight="280"
          showStatusBar="false"
          systemChrome="none" transparent="true"
          initialize="_init()" creationComplete="_initPostCreation()"
          maximizable="false" minimizable="false" xmlns:Components="assets.skins.CompOverlay.Components.*">

    <fx:Declarations>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:VGroup left="2" top="2" right="2" bottom="2" gap="0">        
        <s:Label width="100%" textAlign="center" text="Window Scale" fontSize="14" />
        <s:HGroup width="100%">
            <s:HSlider id="winScale" minimum="0.6" maximum="2" width="80%" snapInterval="0.01" showDataTip="false" change="_winScale(event)" />
            <s:Label width="20%" fontSize="14" textAlign="center" text="{Math.round(winScale.value*100) + '%'}"/>
        </s:HGroup>     
    </s:VGroup>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.ResizeEvent;

            private function _init():void
            {

            }

            private function _initPostCreation():void
            {
                this.addEventListener(Event.CLOSING, this._destructor);

                this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
                this.stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, _onResize);
                this.addEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, _onWinResize);
                this.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            }

            private function _destructor(event:Event):void
            {               
                this.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSING, this._destructor);
                this.stage.removeEventListener(Event.RESIZE, _onResize);
                this.removeEventListener(ResizeEvent.RESIZE, _onWinResize);
            }

            private function _winScale(event:Event):void
            {
                this.scaleX = event.target.value;
                this.scaleY = this.scaleX;
                this.width = (260*this.scaleX);
                this.height = (300*this.scaleY);
                trace(this.width, this.height);
                trace(this.scaleX, this.scaleY);
            }

            private function _onResize(event:Event):void
            {
                trace('start resize----');
                trace('stage.width = '+this.stage.width, 'stage.height = '+this.stage.height);
                trace('stage.stageWidth = '+this.stage.stageWidth, 'stage.stageHeight = '+this.stage.stageHeight);
                if (this.initialized) {
                    if (this.stage.width != this.stage.stageWidth) {
                        this.stage.removeEventListener(Event.RESIZE, _onResize);

                        this.stage.stageWidth = this.stage.width;
                        this.stage.stageHeight = this.stage.height;

                        this.stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, _onResize);
                    }
                    trace('stage.width = '+this.stage.width, 'stage.height = '+this.stage.height);
                    trace('stage.stageWidth = '+this.stage.stageWidth, 'stage.stageHeight = '+this.stage.stageHeight);
                    trace('stage.scaleX = '+this.stage.scaleX, 'stage.scaleY = '+this.stage.scaleY);
                }
                trace('end resize----');
            }

            private function _onWinResize(event:ResizeEvent):void
            {
                trace ('window resize event');
                if (this.stage.width != this.stage.stageWidth) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    trace('prop stopped');
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Window>
```

Resizing the window a few times results in this trace output:

```
start resize----
stage.width = 291.5 stage.height = 316.9
stage.stageWidth = 275 stage.stageHeight = 297
window resize event
prop stopped
window resize event
prop stopped
stage.width = 308.45 stage.height = 337.05
stage.stageWidth = 291 stage.stageHeight = 316
stage.scaleX = 1 stage.scaleY = 1 stage.scaleMode = noScale
end resize----
window resize event
prop stopped
start resize----
stage.width = 308.45 stage.height = 339.2
stage.stageWidth = 291 stage.stageHeight = 318
window resize event
prop stopped
window resize event
prop stopped
stage.width = 326.5 stage.height = 361.45
stage.stageWidth = 308 stage.stageHeight = 339
stage.scaleX = 1 stage.scaleY = 1 stage.scaleMode = noScale
end resize----
```

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: I personally never ever use `stage.width`. I don't know what it's for but I'm betting that it's the same as `Sprite.width`, which is just the width of a box that contains its children. In any case I haven't needed to use it yet myself and for actually getting or changing the real stage dimensions, `stage.stageWidth` is the only thing that matters. I'll take a closer look at your code later on and see if I can understand exactly what you're trying to do though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From the research I've done, what you said about stage.width is correct. But when I change stage.stageWidth, the contents of the window are scaled again, so stage.width always ends up being wider that stage.stageWidth. The scale of the window is not the same as the scale of the stage, but I can't figure out how to fix that.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to do now. Unfortunately I can't really see why you want to do it, but I can't see why it isn't doing it either. I'm not very experienced in Flex though, I use pure AS3, so the way you deal with windows might not be familiar to me. I'll try and see if I can figure it out though.

Comment: I'm trying to accommodate for different screen resolutions and the end user's desire to increase or decrease the overall size of the application. For example, on my screen at 1920x1080, the program looks fine, but the end user may be using a smaller resolution and the application would be a lot bigger and occupy more screen space. I would like to allow them to scale the application down in size if that is the case.